# Как реализовать рассылку на AIOGRAM?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет. Я только начанаю все изучать, так что не кидайтесь в меня тапками. Как реализовать следующее:

1. Я отправляю в бот фразу Рассылка
2. Бот спрашивает у меня ID сообщения из канала
3. После отправки ID сообщения, бот пересылает сообщение из канала по списку ID пользователей из отдельного файла

Буду очень благодарен всем, кто не пройдём мимо и поможет!

Comment: так вы же уже довольно подробно описали алгоритм действий, осталось это переложить на код, если не будет что-то получаться, что задавайте вопросы, прикладывайте код, с которым у вас возникают эти проблемы и вам помогут. Небольшое дополнение касаемо третьего пункта - когда будете заводить файл с ID пользователей имейте ввиду, что бот не может являться инициатором диалога